# Wondering why my SQL statement is ignoring my SET symbol

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, triggers

This is my SQL trigger and it is suppose to change the reorder value to Y or N depending if ON_HAND is less than or greater than the MINIMUM. The problem is it's ignoring the set statement completely. Do I have to arrange these differently?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_REORDER 
AFTER UPDATE OF ON_HAND, MINIMUM ON PART

BEGIN

IF ON_HAND <= MINIMUM THEN
   SET REORDER = 'Y';
ELSE ON_HAND > MINIMUM
   SET REORDER = 'N';

END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Does this even compile?

Comment: This code does not compile. It ignores the set statement.

Comment: When you say ***ignore*** in your question, you give the impression that the trigger is actually executing properly, but not running that specific line of code.  In your case, the `SET` is not your only problem.  The whole trigger is not written in proper Oracle syntax.

Comment: I do know SET isn't the only problem. I'm not quite sure how to write IF statements in Oracle. From what I've been looking at there have been a couple different ways of doing it. I haven't found one that works.

Comment: It sounds like you are going about this using trial and error. That won't be a pleasant experience for you in the long run.  Consider taking a step back and taking the time to read relevant portions of the [PL/SQL reference documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/toc.htm).

Comment: `set` is invalid PL/SQL syntax. What is that supposed to do? You also have no variable named `REORDER` or `ON_HAND`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Oracle triggers but I suspect you want a *BEFORE* trigger and an assignment that looks something like this.

```
:new.REORDER := case when :new.ON_HAND <= :new.MINIMUM then 'Y' else 'N' end;
```

Check here to get started:
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_update.php

Comment: It has to be after. When the MINIMUM or ON_HAND gets updated THEN the REORDER is changed. Say the MINIMUM is 2 and ON_HAND is 5. Then the REORDER will be N since the ON_HAND is larger than MINIMUM.

Comment: Yeah, the trigger occurs when an update happens but prior to actually saving the values. That's when you want this to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Trigger bodies use PL/SQL syntax, not SQL.  So for assignment you need `:=` not `set`.

Your code has some other syntax errors.

- You need to refer to the `:new` values of the columns.
- You don't need a condition in the ELSE clause.
- In order to modify the values of columns in a trigger, it must be a BEFORE trigger and fire FOR EACH ROW.

So fixing all that, this should now work for you (caveat: untested code).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_REORDER 
before UPDATE OF ON_HAND, MINIMUM ON PART
for each row
BEGIN

   IF :new.ON_HAND <= :new.MINIMUM THEN
       :new.REORDER = 'Y';
   ELSE 
       :new.REORDER = 'N';
    END IF;
END;
```